# how to get form option items from request attribute

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am generating an ArrayList of dropdown values and assigning it to request attribute. Can I retrieve it directly from my jsp page or do I need to do something else? Because I get

```
Type [java.lang.String] is not valid for option items exception
```

In my controller:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("LCCLSTypeCode", new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(arr)));
```

in my jsp page:

```
<form:options items="${LCCLSTypeCode}" itemValue="idValue" itemLabel="displayValue"/>
```

I have browsed enough to see examples where the arraylist has been assigned through model.addAttribute

I want to know whether I can do like this and what is the mistake I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a map to session because form:option takes idvalue and display value

Comment: When i printed the arraylist, it displayed something as below `ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(arr));
  System.out.println("arrayList:"+arrayList);` printed result as `[idValue: ; displayValue: , 
idValue: AddtlConditions; displayValue: Additional Conditions, 
idValue: DocsRequired; displayValue: Documents Required, 
idValue: DraftsAt2; displayValue: Drafts At Terms, 
idValue: Charges; displayValue: Instructions for Fees and Charges, 
idValue: MerchDesc; displayValue: Merchandise Description, 
idValue: Variance; displayValue: Variance]` Does it not have key value pair?

Comment: I tried converting the arraylist to Map `Map hashMap = new HashMap();
  for(int i = 0;i<arrayList.size();i++){
   hashMap.put(i, arrayList.get(i));
  }`. It printed `0=idValue: ; displayValue: , 
1=idValue: AddtlConditions; displayValue: Additional Conditions, 
2=idValue: DocsRequired; displayValue: Documents Required, 
3=idValue: DraftsAt2; displayValue: Drafts At Terms, 
4=idValue: Charges; displayValue: Instructions for Fees and Charges, 
5=idValue: MerchDesc; displayValue: Merchandise Description, 
6=idValue: Variance; displayValue: Variance`. But even this gave out the same error.Pls help

Answer (score 0):

dropdown require id and value,so you have to use map with key-value pair.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the dropdown map to model attribute and retrieving it in the jsp page, solved the error. 
But my main motive is to get it attached to the session object, which I am not able to do. Because in my form submit, I will again redirect to the same page only. So if I attach my dropdown to session object, I will not have to generate the dropdown each and every time and attach it to the model object.

Controller:

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
modelAndView.setViewName("menu1");
modelAndView.addObject("command", new ClauseData());
modelAndView.addObject("LCCLSTypeCode", newMap);
return modelAndView;
```

JSP page:

```
<%
Map LCCLSTypeCode = (Map) request.getAttribute("LCCLSTypeCode"); 
System.out.println("LCCLSTypeCode:"+LCCLSTypeCode);
%>
.
.
.
.
<form:select path="typeCode">
<form:options items="<%=LCCLSTypeCode%>" itemValue="idValue" itemLabel="displayValue"/>
</form:select>
```

However now I am getting a different exception which I have posted as a  [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29387819/org-springframework-beans-notreadablepropertyexception-invalid-property-idvalu)

Comment: refer to answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29387819/org-springframework-beans-notreadablepropertyexception-invalid-property-idvalu/29403992#29403992